# Android - ApplicationID and package must be the same?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, package-name

What the differences between those two?
and if ApplicationID and package are not the same, something will happened?

thanks.

Comment: Check that : http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

Comment: Already answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38347268/androidwhich-one-to-use-for-package-name-manifests-packagename-or-gradle-appl

Comment: Although your project's package name matches the application ID by default, **you can change it**. However, if you want to change your package name, be aware that the package name (as defined by your project directory structure) should always match the package attribute in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In manifest you got package name

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapp" <!--this is package name-->
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
```

and in Gradle file ApplicationId

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
defaultConfig {
 applicationId 'com.example.myapp'  //ApplicationID
  minSdkVersion 16
  targetSdkVersion 23
  versionCode 1
  versionName "1.0"
}
```

[Doc](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename)

> The final package that is used in your built .apk's manifest, and is
>   the package your app is known as on your device and in the Google Play
>   store, is the "application id".
>
> The package that is used in your source code to refer to your R class,
>   and to resolve any relative activity/service registrations, continues
>   to be called the "package".

Comment: Thank you Ganesh for your response.

Comment: I'm just a little bit confused, why there is just package or just Id if they needs to be the same.

Comment: I don't know exactly but we are using ADT and SDK from a long time before Android studio came in picture,  but build system change to ANT to Gradle I think this is bridge of this two

Comment: If posted answer resolves your problem then accept this :)

Answer (score 2):

From [ApplicationId versus PackageName](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename)

> The final package that is used in your built .apk's manifest, and is the package your app is known as on your device and in the Google Play store, is the "application id".
>
> The package that is used in your source code to refer to your R class, and to resolve any relative activity/service registrations, continues to be called the "package".