# Firebase Cloud Messaging - applicationid occurs error

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am adding Firebase cloud messaging. However, when I write applicationid in androidmanifest file, an error occurs:

```
"obj\Debug\android\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml:9: Tag <category> attribute name has invalid character '$'.
```

The `AndroidManifest.xml` is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I write applicationid in androidmanifest file, an error occurs
>
> "obj\Debug\android\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml:9: Tag attribute name has invalid character '$'."

You need to replace the whole string `${applicationId}` with your applicationId. So the manifest should look like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    ...
    <category android:name="applicationId"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Notes: ${...} is generally used for native android app to be replaced with settings in `build.gradle` file. Please refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38347268/androidwhich-one-to-use-for-package-name-manifests-packagename-or-gradle-appl).

Update:
Also instead of app id that you get from Firebase, you need to use the Package Name as applicationId, please refer to [Set the Package Name](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/#Set_the_Package_Name):

> In Firebase Cloud Messaging, you specified a package name for the FCM-enabled app. **This package name also serves as the application ID that is associated with the API key**. Configure the app to use this package name:

Comment: this time error is [obj\Debug\android\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml:16: Tag <category> attribute name has invalid character ':']

Comment: Sorry, I thought you used a fake applicationId, you should use package name as the applicationId, please check my update.

Comment: i tried that before, but now it is working. Thanks, very much